# Have Android Date Picker DIALOGUE show for Unity Mobile App

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

How do I have the native Android Date Picker DIALOGUE show up on button press. I had a look at the example on the Unity Docs [unity docs AndroidJavaProxy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaProxy.html) but it only seems to populate the create button with the date and does not bring the Date Picker DIALOGUE up as it suggest it would on the page. Testing on a Samsung Galaxy Note 8. No code provided because it is exactly the same as the LINK PROVIDED.

Comment: The example is about `DatePickerDialog` not `DatePicker` and it works on my phone. If you have problem with the code, please provide more details (code, logcat, screenshot etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using System;

public class SelectedDate
{
    public static DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
}
public class DateCallback : AndroidJavaProxy
{
    public DateCallback() : base("android.app.DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener") { }

    public void onDateSet(AndroidJavaObject view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        SelectedDate.date = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);
    }
}
public class DatePicker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text startingDateText;
    public TMP_Text goalDateText;
    private AndroidJavaObject activity;
    private DateTime newSelectedStartingDate;
    private DateTime newSelectedGoalDate;

    void PickDate()
    {
        new AndroidJavaObject("android.app.DatePickerDialog", activity, new DateCallback(), SelectedDate.date.Year, SelectedDate.date.Month - 1, SelectedDate.date.Day).Call("show");
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 450, 100), string.Format("ddd d MMMM, yyyy", SelectedDate.date)))
        {
            activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
            activity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(PickDate));
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work but only executes correctly through OnGUI where it updates after the Android Date Picker Dialogue has closed. Creating a button in the Unity UI and executing the code on button click does not update until the next time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with type of "activity", which has to be `AndroidJavaObject` and not `AndroidJavaClass`.

Note: The `GetStatic<T>(Object)` method also takes `AndroidJavaObject` as type parameter.

Original:

```
AndroidJavaClass activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaClass>("currentActivity");
```

Fixed:

```
AndroidJavaObject activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
```